# iOS iframe pageshow event not triggered

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, webkit, dom-events

I seem to struggle with attempting to re-instantiate any J/S event listeners in an iframe after the page have been navigated away from and then back to. This seem to only not work in iOS (iPhone 5.x), and works perfectly in other WebKit (i.e. Linux Chrome)

I've published the code at http://manticore.2y.net/fvt/tt.html.

The document has a very simple structure, and there are no J/S frameworks involved.

Main document is effectively an empty shell that loads an iframe, the contents of an iframe have javascript. The sample javascript binds event listener to the image, and there is also an event listener on the text below, specified with the tag attribute. Now, when a link is clicked on the page, another page is displayed (the link is target _top. For _self, things work normally, i.e. the pageshow normally fires). When the user navigates back to the previous page, all the events of the document inside the iframe look dead, and no pageshow event is delivered at that time.

So if you open the link above on iPhone and click on the image, you'll see pop up. As long as you follow the link at the bottom, and return back to the original page, clicks on either the image, or the text, will not execute any j/s.

Is there any workaround to this problem? Especially considering that in real world I will have no control over the main page, and the main page will be on a different domain as well. The only thing that I have found is that if I set up a J/S interval, that thing will resume ticking when I go back to the page, and I can use that in conjunction with listener to 'unload' to re-establish my listeners (and for that matter, am I guaranteed that my timeout wouldn't fire after unload listener returns, and before the page is suspended).

Comment: [Bug 34679 - Location and other objects are dysfunctional after a document gets restored from b/f cache](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34679). I haven't seen any workarounds for iOS 5 :(